# Archimesh vs Archipack

Tags: add-on, archipack-add-on, archimesh-add-on

So now, with 2.79, there are two architecture addons.

1. Do they serve different purposes?
2. Do archipack replace archimesh?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Archimesh basically is a collection of existing cad addons packaged and extended by Antonioya. (window maker, door maker, a wall generator, blinds..)

Archipack is a framework intended to provide parametric objects developpers a fast and easy way to program, focusing on mesh generation, and providing on-screen real-time manipulation, native preset and material handling, and strongest support for linked objects. 
Inspired by archimesh, current implemented objects are ment to boost users productivity with a fast and reliable way to get "ready to render" models.
See [Archipack wiki](https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/wiki)

Comment: Does this mean that Archipack will eventually supersede  Achimesh

Comment: Users will choose and only time will say. Archimesh still provide blinds / kitchen / and some furnitures. On the other hand, archipack does provide a powerfull roof object.

Comment: ...and a better stair object.

Comment: what about an integration between both ?

Comment: An integration [1] for missing features is planed, but the logic behind is somewhat different and those missing objects will require som work.
In the meantime nothing prevent you to use both. 
[1] https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/projects/4

Comment: You should probably disclose that you're slightly biased as the author of Archipack

Comment: Nothing hidden here, contributed in archimesh for 2.79. Archimesh was not fitting with my needs so made my own. So would rather say well informed.

Comment: I don't agree: you should add a disclaimer saying that you sell your software (49 €)... So your judgment is necessarily biaised (although your add-on looks great, but it is not the question here).

Comment: In 2.79 / 2.80 era, archipack was free and shared right in blender's sources, and there still is a free version available. Commercial (sustainable) version was not available at time of writing (2017) so basically you are just plain wrong.